# GlobalKTable doesn't have latest data

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I have a JDBC source connector populating a topic that will be used for a GKTable in a streaming app.

```
 final GlobalKTable<String, String> gktCampaign =
    builder.globalTable(TOPIC_CAMPAIGN_DETAIL,
        Materialized.<String, String, KeyValueStore<Bytes, byte[]>>as(STORE_CAMPAIGN_DETAIL)
            .withKeySerde(Serdes.String())
            .withValueSerde(stringSerde));
```

An update has been made to the Campaign source table, and the topic has indeed been updated; yet in the streaming app the GlobalKTable still shows the old data. Why?

Comment: Well, run `kafka-console-consumer` and look at the stream's input topics

Comment: @OneCricketeer: As I said above, I did that and the updates do indeed exist.

Comment: It is that the data never comes or is just late?

Comment: We experience the exact same problem. 
Data in the topic is updated but sometimes these updates never show up in the GlobalKTable and the associated state store.